# Authenticate user using MSAL.js (v2) in Salesforce custom component

Tags: sharepoint, salesforce-lightning

We have created lightning component in salesforce for Sharepoint which allows operations like view, download and update. We have implemented SSO between Salesforce and SharePoint Online using Microsoft Azure Active Directory. We have setup Azure Active Directory application for Graph to access data of SharePoint Online.

To communicate with Sharepoint online, access token of user need to be passed with Sharepoint Graph api. We can get access token using MSAL.js (v2) provided by Microsoft.
But when I am calling msal.acquireTokenPopup(), lightning component does not open microsoft login popup showing error - "SecureWindow.open supports http:, https:, mailto: schemes and relative urls.Failing descriptor: {markup://c:SharepointWidgetUsingGraph}".

I request if anybody can help me out and let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. My solution was to use a combination of LWC and visualforce to overcome the locker service issues. Here's a working example: https://github.com/rwegner7/salesforce-azure-pkce